# Why isn't my second monitor only showing the desktop?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I am running software for my business on a Toshiba laptop running XP.  I would move to Win 7, but even in capability mode, the software doesn't run right.  (explaining why still on xp)  Sometime back, 3-4 years ago, the monitor on the laptop began to misbehave, so I started using a secondary monitor.  All was fine until today. 
Today, the secondary monitor fired up okay, but as soon as I logged into Windows, it would only show the desktop. None of the active windows were showing.  The screen saver runs okay when it time activates.  I attached a different monitor, by regular monitor cable.  The first monitor is USB.  It too, only shows the desktop.
If I run a remote computer application to access this computer, I do see it as it should be seen.  But not every customer I work with (at their location) has wireless internet that I can use that way.
I have updated the drivers. 
I am at a loss.  I need another WinXP computer, but meantime, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you move the mouse onto that screen, right-click, and adjust the display properties?

Answer (score 1):

It's sounding like the primary monitor for your laptop got reset back to the laptop's screen.  You'll need to set the primary monitor to your external monitor and you can find the instructions for that [here](https://www.somaticvision.com/tutorials/switching_monitors).

Of note, this will probably help resolve your issue with moving to Windows 7 as well.  You can find instructions for Windows 7 [here](http://help.wfu.edu/public/computers/windows/how-to-change-dual-monitor-position-in-windows-7).

If you're still having issues with the monitors, then the graphics card drivers for your laptop are altering the settings behind your back and you'll need to use the program that controls the graphics settings to change your monitors around.

If you still can't get it to work, then you can try a docking station and keep the lid of the laptop closed altogether so that it doesn't come on at all.  Some docking stations have power buttons on them that allow you to keep the lid of the laptop closed and still be able to power them on.  You'll need an external mouse and keyboard though if you go this route.

Comment: if you are comfortable doing a bit of disassembly on your laptop, you can also take it apart and disconnect the screen cable from the motherboard. This way it will see your external display as the only one and therefore primary. This procedure can be complex, or fairly simple depending on your laptop. If you are very comfortable, you could even try removing the screen altogether (though this would likely disable your wifi and camera)